# Jquery find a div with certain offset

Tags: jquery, offset

Let say i have 10 div's on a page , so what i want is to change the color of the div which has an offset.left = 10 and offset.top = 10.

I am not sure how practical this question is, but i am looking for a jquery code which can help me finding a div with certain offset.

And yes these div's are created dynamically so please do not provide any hacks with html because their position on the page is also dynamic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div').each(function() {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  if (offset.left == 10 && offset.top == 0) {
    // do your stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know, there is a jQuery Utility EXACTLY for this kinda of thing, so you dont have to use .each every time.

It's not necessarily a better solution, but simply, a more "intended" solution as this is why they made this feature.  It's called [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Use it like so:

```
$("div").filter(function(i) { 
    return $(this).offset().top == 10 && $(this).offset().left == 10 
});
// will render a jQuery object containing ONLY the divs that matach the return
```

See example in 

### **jsFiddle Here**